# Parse string to different variables c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got a string `fdf=232232&lid=19974832&number=1&aa_result1_1=someId1&aa_resuuuuuult2_2=someId2&aa_resuuuult3_3=someId3`

and if `aa` exists I need to take values and add them to dictionary like:

```
var dict =  extendedIds.Add("result1", new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
   {
      {
           "someId1",
           new int[]{ 1 }
      }, ...
   });
```

however I am having a difficult time deciding how to parse it properly? I need to accept multiple `aa` values (the ones that come as resultN, someIdN and a number (which is the number after resultN_NUMBER).

I tried to use substring but that doesn't work as I dont't now the length of word result

Basically it is
`var parameters = $"pam=805700&laaid=19974832&kpm=1&{HttpUtility.UrlEncode("aa_{result}_{number}={id}&aa_{result}_{number}={id}&aa_{result}_{number}={id}", Encoding.UTF8)}";`

So I decode it and get string:
 `var decoded = input.ToString().UrlDecode();`

I need to accept multiple `aa` values, so in this example there would be three values, two of them comes from in bertween `_` one after `=` but I wonder how to take these values then there could be something else also split by `_`...

also I could `var parsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(decoded);` parse to NameValueCollection. but I can't use `parsed.GetValues("aa")` because the key would be e.g. `aa_result1_1` and I never know beforehand what it is

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-5.0

Comment: It won't be a word result in reality

Comment: yes! (also not `aa` in reality)

Comment: I mean I changed these values now for an example, in real life `result` will be some kind of url, `aa` will be different string but it will be same everywhere

Comment: Can you explain the rules by which you go from your input string to your dictionary? Would a Split on `_` help?

Comment: I made an update @HansKeﬆing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this set you on the right track?

```
var qs = "fdf=232232&lid=19974832&number=1&aa_result1_1=someId1&aa_resuuuuuult2_2=someId2&aa_resuuuult3_3=someId3";
var nvc = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(qs);
foreach (var key in nvc.AllKeys.Where(k => k.StartsWith("aa")))
{
    var id = nvc[key];
    var parts = key.Split('_');
    var result = parts[1];
    var number = parts[2];
    
    Console.WriteLine($"result = '{result}', number = '{number}' => id = '{id}'");
}
```

- Use [ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring) to convert your string into a NameValueCollection.
- Then use each key that starts with "aa"
- Get its value - this is your "id"
- [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) the key on the `_`
- Ignore the first part (which would be "aa") and use the next two parts

Of course you would want to add some safety: I now assume that there always are 3 parts in that key. Plus you want to do something useful with the results.

The above code prints this

> result = 'result1', number = '1' => id = 'someId1'
> result = 'resuuuuuult2', number = '2' => id = 'someId2'
> result = 'resuuuult3', number = '3' => id = 'someId3'

Answer (score 4):

this is a query string, you can use  `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to parse it

see

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=net-5.0